# How can I move the metafor plot without moving the rest of the text?

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am trying to get my forest plot centered in the white space using the metafor package. I am trying to move just the plot alone without moving the text columns. Does anyone have any suggestions? The plot is coded using the forest() function with the metafor package.

```
library(metafor)

labela <- as.character(c("Sex (male vs. female)", "   50 to <60", "   60", 
                         "   <18.5", "   25 to <30", "   30 to <35", "   35 to <40", 
                         "   40", "Cancer diagnosis (yes vs. no)", "   Previous", "   Current", 
                         "   Special occasions only", "   One to three times a month", 
                         "   Once or twice a week", "   Three or four times a week", 
                         "   Daily or almost daily", "Oral contraceptive pill (ever vs. never)", 
                         "Hormone replacement therapy (ever vs. never)", "Fracture in the last 5 years (yes vs. no)", "Previous deep vein thrombosis (yes vs. no)", "Previous pulmonary embolism (yes vs. no)"))
labela <- factor(labela, levels = unique(labela))
hazardsa <- log(c(1.44, 1.57, 2.46, 0.78, 1.35, 1.78, 2.29, 3.30, 1.58, 1.03, 1.24, 0.99, 0.87, 0.89, 0.74, 0.80, 0.88, 1.07, 1.19, 3.34, 1.82))
lowera <- log(c(1.29, 1.41, 2.22, 0.43, 1.25, 1.62, 2.02, 2.81, 1.45, 0.96, 1.12, 0.87, 0.76, 0.79, 0.65, 0.71, 0.79, 0.97, 1.08, 2.96, 1.51))
uppera <- log(c(1.60, 1.75, 2.73, 1.40, 1.47, 1.95, 2.60, 3.88, 1.73, 1.10, 1.36, 1.12, 0.99, 1.00, 0.83, 0.90, 0.99, 1.18, 1.31, 3.77, 2.20))
patient_numa <- c(229134, 167158, 217493, 2626, 212127, 87557, 24994, 9704, 41700, 173070, 52979, 58012, 55858, 129297, 115445, 101774, 220446, 103919, 47466, 9323, 3955)
event_numa <- c(2685, 1347, 2935, 11, 2007, 1145, 415, 227, 674, 1863, 572, 675, 525, 1252, 937, 985, 1565, 1030, 559, 440, 175)
pa <- c("<0.001", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "<0.001","0.47", "<0.001", "0.87", "0.04", "0.05", "<0.001", "<0.001", "0.03", "0.15", "<0.001", "<0.001", "<0.001")
forestplota <- data.frame(labela, hazardsa, lowera, uppera, event_numa, patient_numa, pa)
forestplota$patient_numa <- rev(forestplota$patient_numa)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))
pdf(file = "figure1.pdf", width = 15, height = 8.5)
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
forest(rev(hazardsa), ci.lb = rev(lowera), ci.ub = rev(uppera), slab = rev(labela), xlim = c(-5,7), 
       xlab = "Adjusted Hazard Ratio for Venous Thromboembolism Event", 
       refline = 0, annotate = T, ylim = c(-1, 29), ilab = cbind(forestplota$patient_numa, rev(event_numa), rev(pa)), 
       ilab.xpos=c(-1,-0.25, 6.5), at = log(c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6)), rows = c(2:11,13:14, 16:21, 23:24,26), 
       cex = 1, yaxs = "i", textpos = c(NA, 6), atransf = exp)
text(-5, 27.29, pos = 4, "Variable")
text(-1.3, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nPatients")
text(-0.5, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nEvents")
text(4.82, 27.69, pos = 4, "Hazard Ratio \n(95% CI)")
text(6.2, 27.32, pos = 4, "P-value")
text(6.21, 23.5, pos = 4, "<0.001")
text(6.21, 19, pos = 4, "<0.001")

text(-5, c(25, 22, 15, 12), pos=4, c("Age, years (vs. <50)", "Body mass index* (vs. 18.5 to <25)", "Smoking (vs. never)", "Alcohol (vs. never)"))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust `xlim = c(-5,7)`. Maybe `xlim = c(-8,5)` and then of course you need to adjust the other positions, like `ilab.xpos=c(-4, -2.25, 4.5)` and `textpos = c(NA, 4)`, and then position the rest.

P.S.: The `par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))` should go inside the `pdf() [...] dev.off()` part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try: It was really hard. There are a lot of things that you have to do by hand. And if you change one thing others will also change. Not really easy to understand.
Main tweak was done by adapting `xlim` and adding `alim`. `ilab.xpos=` needs to be adapted as well as `text` positions:

```
library(metafor)

labela <- as.character(c("Sex (male vs. female)", "   50 to <60", "   60", 
                         "   <18.5", "   25 to <30", "   30 to <35", "   35 to <40", 
                         "   40", "Cancer diagnosis (yes vs. no)", "   Previous", "   Current", 
                         "   Special occasions only", "   One to three times a month", 
                         "   Once or twice a week", "   Three or four times a week", 
                         "   Daily or almost daily", "Oral contraceptive pill (ever vs. never)", 
                         "Hormone replacement therapy (ever vs. never)", "Fracture in the last 5 years (yes vs. no)", "Previous deep vein thrombosis (yes vs. no)", "Previous pulmonary embolism (yes vs. no)"))
labela <- factor(labela, levels = unique(labela))
hazardsa <- log(c(1.44, 1.57, 2.46, 0.78, 1.35, 1.78, 2.29, 3.30, 1.58, 1.03, 1.24, 0.99, 0.87, 0.89, 0.74, 0.80, 0.88, 1.07, 1.19, 3.34, 1.82))
lowera <- log(c(1.29, 1.41, 2.22, 0.43, 1.25, 1.62, 2.02, 2.81, 1.45, 0.96, 1.12, 0.87, 0.76, 0.79, 0.65, 0.71, 0.79, 0.97, 1.08, 2.96, 1.51))
uppera <- log(c(1.60, 1.75, 2.73, 1.40, 1.47, 1.95, 2.60, 3.88, 1.73, 1.10, 1.36, 1.12, 0.99, 1.00, 0.83, 0.90, 0.99, 1.18, 1.31, 3.77, 2.20))
patient_numa <- c(229134, 167158, 217493, 2626, 212127, 87557, 24994, 9704, 41700, 173070, 52979, 58012, 55858, 129297, 115445, 101774, 220446, 103919, 47466, 9323, 3955)
event_numa <- c(2685, 1347, 2935, 11, 2007, 1145, 415, 227, 674, 1863, 572, 675, 525, 1252, 937, 985, 1565, 1030, 559, 440, 175)
pa <- c("<0.001", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "<0.001","0.47", "<0.001", "0.87", "0.04", "0.05", "<0.001", "<0.001", "0.03", "0.15", "<0.001", "<0.001", "<0.001")
forestplota <- data.frame(labela, hazardsa, lowera, uppera, event_numa, patient_numa, pa)
forestplota$patient_numa <- rev(forestplota$patient_numa)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))
pdf(file = "figure1.pdf", width = 15, height = 8.5)
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
forest(rev(hazardsa), ci.lb = rev(lowera), ci.ub = rev(uppera), slab = rev(labela), xlim = c(-11,8), alim = c(-11,8),
       xlab = "Adjusted Hazard Ratio for Venous Thromboembolism Event", 
       refline = 0, annotate = T, ylim = c(-1, 29), ilab = cbind(forestplota$patient_numa, rev(event_numa), rev(pa)), 
       ilab.xpos=c(-5.5,-4.25, 6.5), at = log(c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6)), rows = c(2:11,13:14, 16:21, 23:24,26), 
       cex = 1, yaxs = "i", textpos = c(NA, 6), atransf = exp)
text(-11, 27.29, pos = 4, "Variable")
text(-6, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nPatients")
text(-4.6, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nEvents")
text(4.22, 27.69, pos = 4, "Hazard Ratio \n(95% CI)")
text(6, 27.32, pos = 4, "P-value")
text(6, 23.5, pos = 4, "<0.001")
text(6, 19, pos = 4, "<0.001")

text(-11, c(25, 22, 15, 12), pos=4, c("Age, years (vs. <50)", "Body mass index* (vs. 18.5 to <25)", "Smoking (vs. never)", "Alcohol (vs. never)"))
dev.off()
```

[image]